# Go mod: not able to retrieve submodules for private repo

Tags: go, go-get

I have 3 go projects. Project A relies on a submodule of project B and module of project C
eg:

```
gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectB/contract
gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectC
```

When go mod tries to download the modules, module C is correctly downloaded but module B fails:

```
get "gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectB/contract": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
go: gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectB/contract@v0.1.0: reading gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectB/contract/projectB/contract/go.mod at revision projectB/contract/v0.1.0: unknown revision projectB/contract/v0.1.0
```

We see that go is trying to read:

```
gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectB/contract/**projectB/contract**/go.mod
```

instead of

```
gitlab.com/myorg/myGroup/projectB/contract/go.mod
```

I've created tag v0.1.0 and contract/v0.1.0 in the repository.

Any idea why go cannot download the modules?

Ps: I've set GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/myorg"

Comment: Add `go.mod` file , please.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this recently with go 1.13, what worked for us was

- `GO111MODULE=on`
- `GOSUMDB=off`
- setting `GOPRIVATE`
- Lastly, using a personal access token with github `git config --global url."https://${TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"`

Comment: Very helpful.  GOSUMDB seems to need to be "off".  FYI can set GO111MODULE=auto